# Oracle sql dev, display Jobs with more then 10 users, group function

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently for my database, im looking to find Jobs which have at least 10 interested users.
I want it to display the jobNum, title and total number of interested users. I'm having a problem with my group function and understanding how to check for 10 users.

```
(PK) = Primary Key
(FK) = Foreign Key
```

The database schema is as follows:

```
Building(buildingNum(PK), Description, instname, buildName, state, postcode)
User(UNum(PK), buildingNum(FK), Surname, FirstName, initials, title)
File(FileNum(PK), title)
UserAccount(FileNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK))
Job(JobNum(PK), id, title)
Interest(JobNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK), Description)
```

So far i have tried the following block of code:

```
select J.JobNum, J.title, count(I.UNum)
from Job J join Interest I
where I.JobNum = J.JobNum and count(I.UNum) > 10
group by J.JobNum, J.title;
```

I was wondering if anyone knows why the group function isn't working and how i should be checking for how many users are interested in the job? Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: If you want "at least 10" you should be using `>= 10`.  This doesn't fix the query, just the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `count()` condition to a `HAVING` clause. `JOIN` wants an `ON` clause for the join condition(s), not a `WHERE` clause.

```
select J.JobNum, J.title, count(I.UNum)
from Job J join Interest I
    ON I.JobNum = J.JobNum 
group by J.JobNum, J.title
having count(I.UNum) > 10
```